# Динамическая подстановка модели vue js

Tags: vue.js

Как сделать так, чтобы массивы "buyingSelling", "buyingSellingRent", "rent" динамически подставлялись в код (см ниже html документ)

```
var showTreeCheckbox = new Vue({
  el: '#tree-checkbox',
  data: {
    showActivity: false,
    buyingSelling: [],
    buyingSellingRent: [],
    rent: [],
    checkItems: [
      {
        key: 'Покупка-Продажа',
        value: ['Жилой недвижимости', 'Коммерческой недвижимости', 'Земельных участков']
      },
      {
        key: 'Покупка-Продажа-Аренда',
        value: ['Приносящей доход недвижимости (Бизнеса)']
      },
      {
        key: 'Аренда',
        value: ['Жилой недвижимости','Коммерческой недвижимости']
      }
    ]
  }
})


<div id="tree-checkbox">

            <div class="check1">
                <input type="checkbox" id="ch1" v-model="showActivity">     
                <label for="ch1"><span>Посредник</span></label>             
            </div>

            <div class="types-activity" v-if="showActivity">
                <h3>Виды и направления деятельности:</h3>
                <label>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="realtorServices">
                    <span>Риелторские услуги</span>
                </label>

                <div class="checkbox-tree-items">

                    <ul>
                        <li v-for="(checkItem,index) in checkItems">
                            <label>
                                <input type="checkbox" :value="checkItem.value" >
                                <span>{{ checkItem.key }}</span>
                            </label>
                            <ul>
                                <li v-for="(subItem,index2) in checkItem.value">
                                    <label>
                                        <input type="checkbox" :value="checkItem.value[index2]+index">
                                        <span>{{ subItem }}</span>
                                        <span>{{  }}</span>
                                    </label>
                                </li>   
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>

                </div><!-- checkbox-tree-items  -->
            </div><!-- types-activity  -->
        </div>
```

Модель нужно подставить вот сюда: `<input type="checkbox" :value="checkItem.value[index2]+index">`
Для того, чтобы выбранные checkbox попадали в свой массив.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не понятно, как вы это потом будете обрабатывать:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-if="0 == index" v-model="buyingSelling" :value="subItem">
<input type="checkbox" v-if="1 == index" v-model="buyingSellingRent" :value="subItem">
<input type="checkbox" v-if="2 == index" v-model="rent" :value="subItem">
```

Добавьте в ваш код для визуализации изменений:

```
<pre>{{ buyingSelling }}</pre>
<pre>{{ buyingSellingRent }}</pre>
<pre>{{ rent }}</pre>
```

Вывод информации будет примерно следующим, при выборе интересующих `checkbox`

```
["Жилой недвижимости", "Коммерческой недвижимости", "Земельных участков"]
["Приносящей доход недвижимости (Бизнеса)"]
["Жилой недвижимости", "Коммерческой недвижимости"]
```

Для отображения массива индексов, замените соответственно:

```
<input type="checkbox" v-if="0 == index" v-model="buyingSelling" :value="index2">
<input type="checkbox" v-if="1 == index" v-model="buyingSellingRent" :value="index2">
<input type="checkbox" v-if="2 == index" v-model="rent" :value="index2">
```

```
[0, 1, 2]
[0]
[0, 1]
```

---

**PS** Вариант с индексами гораздо удачнее.

Comment: Благодарю! Надеюсь. получится!